# RegEx Capturing multiple variables

Tags: regex

How can I capture the bolded parts:

> "_id": "**12345abcd**",
>
> "_rev": "1-**abti-2745**",
>
> "question": "**How old are you?**",

I need to do this all on one RegEx expression.

This is what I have so far:

```
/("_id": "(.*?)")|("_rev": "(.*)")/is
```

or

```
/"_id": "(.*)",.*?"_rev": "?(.*)"?,/is
```

Comment: What does the data look like? Is it on multiple lines as the post shows? What have you tried? Also, why do you feel this needs to be done in all one expression?

Comment: That's all we have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use. Look-ahead, look-behinds, You can try:

```
"[^"]*":\s"([^"]*)",
```

The bold area is in the first and only capturing group.

Comment: op don't want to capture `1-`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
"_?(?:id|rev|question)":\s*"(?:.*?-)?([^"]*)",
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fV5oS0/6)

**Explanation:**

- `_?` Optional Underscore symbol.
- `(?:id|rev|question)":` Non-capturing group which matches the string `id` or `rev` or `question` and also the following `":` characters.
- `\s*` Matches zero or more space characters.
- `(?:.*?-)?` Shortest match upto the first - symbol. `?` after the non-capturing group makes it as an optional one.
- `([^"]*)` Captures any charcter not of `"` zero or more times.
- `",` Matches the literal `",` symbols.

Comment: I think that `"_?(?:id|rev|question)"` is a too literal. Why not `"[^"]+"`. That will only work for ones that have `id` `rev` and `question` in front. [Take a look](http://regex101.com/r/fV5oS0/7)
and a [more general regex](http://regex101.com/r/fV5oS0/8)

Comment: no, it would match any charcter not of `"` one or more times. I put the above specific regex because op has included the strings `rev`, `id` in his pattern. If he intended to make a general regex then your's  would be enough.

Comment: yes, for general `"[^"]+":\s*"(?:.*?-)?([^"]*)",` would be helpful.